# Problems with the /var/www folder

Tags: 12.04, permissions, apache2, php

I am new to Ubuntu, I've installed 12.04. I used to use wamp server on Windows, and after changing OS I moved some files from www folder to `/var/www` on Ubuntu. But when I try to view that folder in a browser it doesn't display anything.

Probably there is a problem with permission issues. What are proper permissions for `/var/www` folder? Here are my `/var` folder permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root     1024 Feb  4 20:06 www
```

I have run

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www  
chown -R root /var/www
```

Right now that `/var/www` folder is empty, but how can I configure apache to show files under that folder in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default apache is configured to show following files instead of directory listing:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
```

You can recursively list all these with this:

```
find /var/www -name 'index.*'
```

If your directory have any of those, apache will show it, instead of something like this:

[image: Example of apache file listing]

To fix that, delete or rename index.* files to something else. Alternatively, you can change `DirectoryIndex` directive and reload apache (`/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`).

By default, apache `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www`. Only files under that folder are displayed. Additionally, symlinks are followed only if destination is owned by same user. If you have files under `/var/www`, you don't have to care about that.

Apache does not list files that `www-data` user can not read. As long as there's `r` and `x` the last group (marked with `^` below), everything is fine:

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 user group     4014 Feb  4 23:16 filename
       ^ ^
```

Technically, you only need `x` for folders. Your commands for changing the permissions were correct:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

If apache does not list any files even if you don't have any index files on your folder, use

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

to see which errors apache encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Install Apache using following command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Now, open `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file check if following line is present

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

If any other path is present, change it to `/var/www`

Now you can put any html file to view it in your browser. Also, if you add `index.html` to `/var/www` and visit `http://localhost/` in browser, you will be able to see it.

Comment: Actually I've already install apache and all other elements, and yes that line is present.. I can view files that I created in the folder, but I can't view that specific folder that I copied from Windows, although it almost doesn't contain php code that could have an error. So there must be a permission issue, or may be I should change group to www-data?! ps I have added myself to that group..

Comment: You don't have to add yourself to that group. `root` is just fine as owner of those files - actually it's better than `www-data`, because then apache do not have permission to modify or remove those files.